# TCPDF remove <ul> indenting

Tags: html, margin, tcpdf, spacing

For some reason TCPDF is adding space to the left when I use `writeHTML()` to print an unordered list. By default, the PDF has a margin of 5 (set with `$pdf->SetMargins(5, 0, 10, true);`) but list items get indented.

I set `$pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);` already, which prevents with unwanted (minus-)space for `<p>` tags, but obviously doesn´t affect lists.

The call:

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<ul><li>...</li></li>...</li></ul>');
```

The result:

[image]

Is there any option I miss?

Answer (score 30):

There is a method `setListIndentWidth`. For example:

```
$pdf->setListIndentWidth(4);
```

You can experiment with the value. And the documentation entry is [here](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_setListIndentWidth).

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: I've updated link to the documentation but currently it's not very useful.

Comment: New link as of 2020 https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_setListIndentWidth

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

find `$this->lMargin += $this->listindent;` in tcpdf.php and replace with `$this->lMargin += $this->listindent/2;`

Answer (score -3):

change:

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<ul><li>...</li></li>...</li></ul>');
```

to:

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><li>...</li></li>...</li></ul>');
```

`<ul>` -Tag always adds space to the left (padding) and margin to top.

Comment: Already tried inline-styles… Doesn´t work. As far as I know, TCPDF doesn´t support margin and padding at all.

Comment: I use `html2pdf` in combination with `TCPDF 5.0.002` and it works great.

Comment: I´m just using TCPDF (6.0.044). Maybe it´s because of the combination you use… or the older version, which seems to be different in some ways.

Comment: TCPDF doesn't support margin and padding attributes. The latest 6.2 only support padding in table.